# Can you declare the values for multiple variables on the same line?

Tags: java, syntax

I was writing a Java program, and I tried to declare multiple variables on the same line:

```
class IfSample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int x, y = 10, 20;

        if (x < y) System.out.println("x is less than y.");

        x *= 2;
        if (x == y) System.out.println("x is equal to y.");

        x *= 2;
        if (x > y) System.out.println("x is greater than y.");
    }
}
```

However, this ran an error on VS Code (I'm using the normal Java extension pack made by MS recommended by VS).

The error message: `Syntax error on token "20", invalid VariableDeclarator`.

I'm pretty sure that Python lets you do declare multiple variables on the same line(?), and I though that Java did too. Does Java not let you do this, and if not, does that mean that I have to always declare variables on separate lines, or is there some workaround to this?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: `int x = 10, y = 20;`. But don't do this, there's really no benefit to declaring multiple variables in the same statement: declare and assign each variable separately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Java doesn't allow you to do : `int x, y = 10, 20;`

But java does allow you to **declare multiple variables on the same line** in the following ways:

```
int a, b, c;
int x = 10, y = 20, z = 30;
```